# How to use map in JS and Vue to create a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, vuejs3

I am attempting to set up a map method in JavaScript and Vue that creates a new array of objects while returning only selected items in each object. To accomplish this, I set up a UI with 2 checkboxes corresponding to 2 separate objects:

```
    <div v-for="object in objects" :key="object.id" class="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg justify-center">
      <div class="px-6 py-4">
        <div class="font-bold text-xl mb-2">{{ object.name }}</div>
      </div>
      <span class="flex-1 flex mt-8 m-2">
        <span class="flex flex-col">
          <input v-model="checkBoxArray" :value="object.id" @click="selectObject(object.id)" type="checkbox" class="h-5 w-5" />
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
```

```
  const objects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'bucky barnes',
    title: 'winter soldier',
    cellnum: '123-456-7890',
    email: 'barnes@hydra.com',
    description: 'Description 1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'sam wilson',
    title: 'falcon',
    cellnum: '098-765-4321',
    email: 'falcon@avengers.com',
    description: 'Description 2'
  },
]
```

The selectObject handler on the checkbox input pushes the id of a selected object to checkBoxArray:

```
const checkBoxArray = ref([])

const selectObject = (id) => {
  checkBoxArray.value.push(id)
}
```

Then, a watch property is used to watch for changes to checkBoxArray.value, then call a function that uses map to create a new array targeting the id of the selected object:

```
watch(checkBoxArray.value, () => {
  const storedObjects = objects.map(val => checkBoxArray.value.find(obj => obj === val.id), ['id', 'name', 'title'])
  console.log(storedObjects)
})
```

My expectation is the new array created will be an array with an object containing ONLY the id, name, and title from the original object. example:

```
{id: 1, name: 'bucky barnes', title: 'winter soldier'}
```

However, I currently only returning a new array with the id of the selected object. How can I go about setting up the map and find methods in the watch property to create a new array with an object containing ONLY id, name, and title?

Here is the full code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="object in objects" :key="object.id" class="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg justify-center">
      <div class="px-6 py-4">
        <div class="font-bold text-xl mb-2">{{ object.name }}</div>
      </div>
      <span class="flex-1 flex mt-8 m-2">
        <span class="flex flex-col">
          <input v-model="checkBoxArray" :value="object.id" @click="selectObject(object.id)" type="checkbox" class="h-5 w-5" />
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref, watch } from 'vue';

  const objects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'bucky barnes',
    title: 'winter soldier',
    cellnum: '123-456-7890',
    email: 'barnes@hydra.com',
    description: 'Description 1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'sam wilson',
    title: 'falcon',
    cellnum: '098-765-4321',
    email: 'falcon@avengers.com',
    description: 'Description 2'
  },
]

const checkBoxArray = ref([])

const selectObject = (id) => {
  checkBoxArray.value.push(id)
}

watch(checkBoxArray.value, () => {
  const storedObjects = objects.map(val => checkBoxArray.value.find(obj => obj === val.id), ['id', 'name', 'title'])
  console.log(storedObjects)
})

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(objects)
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no syntax of [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) that filters the fields by 2nd argument:

```
                                                             // This parameter will not work
                                                                          
objects.map(val => checkBoxArray.value.find(obj => obj === val.id), ['id', 'name', 'title'])
```

You should filter the objects that are stored first, then use map to transform them:

```
const storedObjects = objects
.filter(obj => checkBoxArray.value.find(id => id === obj.id)) // this returns the array of object that are stored
.map(elm => {
 return {
   id: elm.id,
   title: elm.title,
   name: elm.name
 }
})
```